# How to understand SO_REUSEPORT can simplify the task of conducting stateful conversations between the client and server?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, server

I'm learning about SO_REUSEPORT socket option, and when I read "https://lwn.net/Articles/542629/", I have a confusion about this sentence:"This eases the task of conducting stateful conversations between the client and server." in the article.

As far as I understand, the SO_REUSEPORT option works on the same machine, and the stateful task between the server and the client is for multiple servers. Why does SO_REUSERPORT have a simplified effect?

What dose "task of conducting stateful conversations between the client and server" mean?Please give some specific examples,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, for examples, reverse proxy server.